# PDO causes memory overflow

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

To get the script working with PHP 5.5 I actually change from mysql-extension to PDO. With the mysql-extension it works fine but with PDO it causes a memory overflow.

Here is the function I use:

```
    protected function getData($table) {
  global $db;
  $insert = '';
  $stmt = $db->query("-- " . __LINE__ . __FILE__ . "
    SELECT *
    FROM   " . $table
  );
  if ($result = $stmt->fetchAll()) {
    $insert_into = "INSERT INTO `" . $table . "` VALUES ". PHP_EOL;
    $insert  = "/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `" . $table . "` DISABLE KEYS */;" . PHP_EOL;
    $insert .= $insert_into;
    $countRow  = 0;
    $split_tmp = '';
    foreach ($result as $row) {
      $insert_tmp = "(";
      foreach ($row as $data) {
        if (!isset($data)) {
          $insert_tmp .= 'NULL,';
        } else if ($data != '') {
          $insert_tmp .= "'" . addslashes($data) . "',";
        } else {
          $insert_tmp .= "'',";
        }
      }
      $insert_tmp = rtrim($insert_tmp, ',') . '),' . PHP_EOL;
      $insert .= $insert_tmp;
      if ($this->querySplit) {
        $split_tmp .= $insert_tmp;
        if ($countRow > $this->maxRow && strlen($split_tmp) > $this->maxLength) {
          $countRow     = 0;
          $split_tmp = '';
          $insert  = rtrim($insert, PHP_EOL . ',') . ';' . PHP_EOL;
          $insert .= "/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `" . $table . "` ENABLE KEYS */;" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
          $insert .= "/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `" . $table . "` DISABLE KEYS */;" . PHP_EOL;
          $insert .= $insert_into;
        }
      }
      $countRow ++;
    }
    $insert = rtrim($insert, PHP_EOL . ',') . ';' . PHP_EOL;
    $insert  .= "/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `" . $table . "` ENABLE KEYS */;" . PHP_EOL. PHP_EOL;
  }
  return $insert;
}
```

Even changing to

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, false);
```

doesn't help.

The memory_limit is set to 256MB.

Comment: PDO doesn't cause the memory overflow, your use of fetchAll() causes the memory overflow. Fetch your rows one at a time

Comment: Your entire result set is getting buffered into memory when you call `fetchAll()`. The trick is to let MySQL do the work where possible by slimming down your result set with your query - ie `SELECT field1, field2` instead of `SELECT *`, especially if the table has a large number of columns. If you're pulling down 50000 rows...well, you can see the issue here, surely? 

Also, why are you calling PHP_EOL 12 times in one short function? Are you calling this via command line or exporting it?

Comment: I need all the table fields because the script is to backup the entire database. So your solution with naming the fields won't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Using `fetchAll` is a very bad idea when dealing with large amount of data, do the following adjustment using `fetch()`

```
protected function getData($table) {
  global $db;
  $insert = '';
  $stmt = $db->query("-- " . __LINE__ . __FILE__ . "
    SELECT *
    FROM   " . $table
  );
  if ($result = $stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
    $insert_into = "INSERT INTO `" . $table . "` VALUES ". PHP_EOL;
    $insert  = "/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `" . $table . "` DISABLE KEYS */;" . PHP_EOL;
    $insert .= $insert_into;
    $countRow  = 0;
    $split_tmp = '';
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
      $insert_tmp = "(";
      foreach ($row as $data) {
        if (!isset($data)) {
          $insert_tmp .= 'NULL,';
        } else if ($data != '') {
          $insert_tmp .= "'" . addslashes($data) . "',";
        } else {
          $insert_tmp .= "'',";
        }
      }
      $insert_tmp = rtrim($insert_tmp, ',') . '),' . PHP_EOL;
      $insert .= $insert_tmp;
      if ($this->querySplit) {
        $split_tmp .= $insert_tmp;
        if ($countRow > $this->maxRow && strlen($split_tmp) > $this->maxLength) {
          $countRow     = 0;
          $split_tmp = '';
          $insert  = rtrim($insert, PHP_EOL . ',') . ';' . PHP_EOL;
          $insert .= "/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `" . $table . "` ENABLE KEYS */;" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
          $insert .= "/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `" . $table . "` DISABLE KEYS */;" . PHP_EOL;
          $insert .= $insert_into;
        }
      }
      $countRow ++;
    }
    $insert = rtrim($insert, PHP_EOL . ',') . ';' . PHP_EOL;
    $insert  .= "/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `" . $table . "` ENABLE KEYS */;" . PHP_EOL. PHP_EOL;
  }
  return $insert;
}
```